# Selecting single radio button, wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox, radio-button

I need to put on my window 3 radio buttons and to make a user to chose only one button.
I made a ListBox and set Selection mode = Single but i still can choose all of them , i need to wrap each item in something...i don't know what and how. Can anyone help? Maybe there is another way for presenting radio buttons and choosing only one...?

here is the xaml -

```
<ListBox SelectionMode="Single" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0,0,0,57" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="304" Height="146" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <ListBoxItem>
            <RadioButton Content="Option 1" Margin="0,0,0,10" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="radioButton1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="12" />
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <RadioButton Content="Option 2" Margin="0,0,0,10" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="radioButton2" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="12" />
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="90">
                <RadioButton Content="Another : " Checked="radioButton4_Checked" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="radioButton4" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="12" />
                <TextBox Width="225" Name="TextBox_AnotherReason" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Although the various GroupName-related answers below are correct, they don't address a more important question: why are you using a ListBox here? By putting radio buttons into a ListBox, you've introduced two mechanisms *both* of which provide a way to select a single item from a list. They effectively compete, so it's no surprise that your example doesn't really work properly. Either use a ListBox, or use a set of RadioButtons. Don't use both.

Comment: good remark, if you use it as a way to layout the checkboxes you better use stackpanel.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the GroupName property on the RadioButton elements (see http://arcanecode.com/2007/09/20/the-wpf-radiobutton/)!

```
<StackPanel>
  <RadioButton GroupName=“One“ IsChecked=“True“>Option 1</RadioButton>
  <RadioButton GroupName=“One“ IsChecked=“False“>Option 2</RadioButton>
  <RadioButton GroupName=“Two“ IsChecked=“False“>Option 3</RadioButton>
  <RadioButton GroupName=“Two“ IsChecked=“True“>Option 4</RadioButton>
</StackPanel>
```

so in your case:

```
<ListBox SelectionMode="Single" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0,0,0,57" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="304" Height="146" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <ListBoxItem>
        <RadioButton GroupName=“Group1“ Content="Option 1" Margin="0,0,0,10" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="radioButton1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="12" />
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <RadioButton GroupName=“Group1“ Content="Option 2" Margin="0,0,0,10" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="radioButton2" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="12" />
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="90">
            <RadioButton GroupName=“Group1“ Content="Another : " Checked="radioButton4_Checked" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="radioButton4" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="12" />
            <TextBox Width="225" Name="TextBox_AnotherReason" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: No , I don't need it to be a ListBox , I was a little confused...After all the remarks , I see my mistake...thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Give them(radio buttons) all a groupname that is same.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give each RadioButton a `GroupName` property, and have it be the same between buttons you wish to be mutually exclusive.